# can I freeze dependency version while installing crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm installing a rust binary like this: `cargo install --root /usr/local --version 0.20.0 cbindgen`

The installation pulls in hashbrown dependency.

A month ago installation completed successfully (hashbrown-0.11.2). Yesterday I ran the `cargo install` again and hashbrown-0.12.2 was selected for installation and installation failed:

```
Step 4/29 : RUN cargo install --root /usr/local --version 0.20.0 cbindgen
 ---> Running in 5a49b461c789
[91m    Updating crates.io index
[0m[91m Downloading crates ...
[0m[91m  Downloaded cbindgen v0.20.0
[0m[91m  Installing cbindgen v0.20.0
[0m[91m Downloading crates ...
[0m[91m  Downloaded remove_dir_all v0.5.3
[0m[91m  Downloaded ryu v1.0.10
[0m[91m  Downloaded serde_derive v1.0.139
[0m[91m  Downloaded textwrap v0.11.0
[0m[91m  Downloaded unicode-width v0.1.9
[0m[91m  Downloaded toml v0.5.9
[0m[91m  Downloaded quote v1.0.20
[0m[91m  Downloaded heck v0.3.3
[0m[91m  Downloaded fastrand v1.7.0
[0m[91m  Downloaded unicode-segmentation v1.9.0
[0m[91m  Downloaded proc-macro2 v1.0.40
[0m[91m  Downloaded strsim v0.8.0
[0m[91m  Downloaded log v0.4.17
[0m[91m  Downloaded clap v2.34.0
[0m[91m  Downloaded vec_map v0.8.2
[0m[91m  Downloaded itoa v1.0.2
  Downloaded libc v0.2.126
[0m[91m  Downloaded atty v0.2.14
[0m[91m  Downloaded hashbrown v0.12.2
[0m[91merror: failed to compile `cbindgen v0.20.0`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/tmp/cargo-installSR6lwa`

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/hashbrown-0.12.2/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  failed to parse the `edition` key

Caused by:
  this version of Cargo is older than the `2021` edition, and only supports `2015` and `2018` editions.
[0mThe command '/bin/sh -c cargo install --root /usr/local --version 0.20.0 cbindgen' returned a non-zero code: 101
section_end:1657590740:step_script
```

is there a way to prevent hashbrown>=0.12 from installing?

Thank you

Comment: a quick solution is update rust with `rustup update`, but if dependencies in `cargo.toml` be something like this `serde_json = "1.0.0"` it's prevent to use another version

Comment: You could install with `cargo --locked`. cbindgen 0.20's lock file specifies hashbrown 0.9.1.

Comment: You really update your Rust version. The fact that it doesn't recognize the `edition = 2021` line (`0.11.2` had `edition = 2018`) means that the Rust version you're running is older than `1.56`.